# Chrome console log in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I use the console tab in Google Chrome to write sometimes for debugging in Jquery.

Can this also be done for the C# `console.write` function?

I have tried `Console`, `trace` and `debug.writeLine` but when in Chrome can never see the values being written anywhere.  Am I using this incorrectly?

Comment: You can log something on server (may be using ajax call ) from your browser logger function

Answer (score 4):

> Am I using this incorrectly?

Yes, C# runs on the server. It cannot output to the browser in that fashion.

You may find this resource useful: [How to trace and debug in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815788)

Comment: The better way is to log the debug message in a file using your Logger function

Comment: @HiteshRiziya - Was that meant for me or the OP? It doesnt make a whole lot of sense to be honest - whats a "Logger" function?

Comment: Thanks mate that has clarified it for me.